# Regex bit in jQuery to target any non-letter, line start or line end

Tags: jquery, regex

What I'm making is an abbreviation definition tooltip, which shows on hover. It's basically an array with a script that searches for abbr instances and adds a couple of divs with classes, and the css does the rest. It's all fine, but I'm unable to overcome one problem:

This line uses regex so I can be sure I'm targeting only the abbreviations and not words that contain them by coincidence (so I excluded all letters and digits). What I want is to also include the instances that appear as the first word in a line (also the last, but this is less important).

```
var newText = $(this).html().replace(new RegExp("([^a-zA-Z0-9.])(" + key + ")([^a-zA-Z0-9.])", 'g'), "$1<span class='definition_trigger'>" + "$2" + "<span class='definition_tooltip'>" + value + "</span></span>$3");
```

I've went thru some regex cheatsheets, tried some different stuff, without any results. Please help guys & gals!

M.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [complete, runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example with expected input and output to get the best answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be nice to see some context of how and what these strings could be looking like.

So this is a just a shot in the dark. Did you try this?

```
new RegExp('^|[^a-zA-Z0-9.])(' + key + ')([^a-zA-Z0-9.]|$)', 'ig')
```

I assume that if an abbr is caught in the beginning it could be using the capital case,
therefore the inclusion of "i".

Comment: Thank you! Works great. Just needed to add one missing bracket:
`new RegExp("(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9.])(" + key + ")([^a-zA-Z0-9.]|$)", "g")`
I also dropped the 'i', as all the abbrvs have specific case, also some of them might (or even would) get mixed up with normal words :)

Answer (score 0):

So here's my full code with Jan's fix (working great!). Someone might find it useful.

```
    <script>
    // TOOLTIP
    $(window).load(function() {
        var theLanguage = $('html').attr('lang');
        if (theLanguage == 'en') {
            var definitions = {
                "ROTFL" : "Rolling On The Floor Laughing"
            };
        }
        if (theLanguage == 'fr') {
            var definitions = {
                "ROTFL" : "Rolling On The Floor Laughing"
            };
        }
        $.each(definitions, function(key, value) {
            $("p:contains(" + key + ")").each(function() {
                var newText = $(this).html().replace(new RegExp("(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9.])(" + key + ")([^a-zA-Z0-9.]|$)", "g"), "$1<span class='definition_trigger'>" + "$2" + "<span class='definition_tooltip'>" + value + "</span></span>$3");
                $(this).html(newText);
            });
        }); 
    });

    // TOOLTIP POSITION
    // This bit makes sure the tooltip stays on screen
    $(window).on("load scroll resize", function() {
        var limitMargin = 63; // Change this according to your sites margin
        $( ".definition_tooltip").each(function( event ) {
          var offset = $( this ).offset();
          var offLeft = (offset.left);
          var offRight = ($(window).width() - ($( this ).offset().left + $( this ).outerWidth()));

            if(offLeft < limitMargin) {
                $(this).removeClass('pushLeft');
                $(this).addClass('pushRight');
            } 
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('pushRight');
            }

            if(offRight < limitMargin) {
                $(this).removeClass('pushRight');
                $(this).addClass('pushLeft');
            } 
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('pushLeft');
            }
        });
          return false;
    });
</script>

<style>
    .definition_trigger {
        position: relative !important;
        cursor: help !important;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd !important;
    }

    .definition_tooltip {
        position: absolute !important;
        left: 50% !important;
        line-height: 1em!important;
        color: #fff!important;
        background-clip: padding-box!important;
        position: absolute!important;
        width: 140px!important;
        left: 50%!important;
        margin-left: -70px!important;
        padding: 5px!important;
        bottom: 150%!important;
        margin-bottom: 15px!important;
        visibility:hidden!important;
        opacity:0!important;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1)!important;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1)!important;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1)!important;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1)!important;
        transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1)!important;
        text-align: center!important;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 #788190 inset!important;
        z-index: 9999!important;
        font-family: 'Whitney Light'!important;
        font-size: 14px !important;
        font-weight: lighter !important;
        text-transform: none !important;
        letter-spacing: 0 !important;
    }

    .definition_tooltip:before, .definition_tooltip:after {
        content: "" !important;
        position: absolute !important;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent !important;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent !important;
        top: 100% !important;
        left: 50% !important;
        margin-left: -10px !important;
    }

    .definition_tooltip:before {
        border-top: 1px solid #788190 !important;
        margin-top: -1px !important;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) !important;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) !important;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) !important;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) !important;
        transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) !important;
    }


    .definition_trigger:hover > .definition_tooltip {
        visibility: visible !important;
        opacity: 0.95 !important;
        bottom: 80% !important;
        box-shadow: 0 -80px 0 #788190 inset !important;
        user-select: none !important;    
        background-color: #788190 !important;
    }

    .definition_trigger:hover > .definition_tooltip::before {
        border-top: 10px solid #788190 !important;
    }

    .definition_tooltip.pushRight {
         margin-left: -30px !important;
    }

    .definition_tooltip.pushRight::before {
         margin-left: -60px !important;
    }


    .definition_tooltip.pushLeft {
         margin-left: -120px !important;
    }

    .definition_tooltip.pushLeft::before {
         margin-left: 30px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20829145)

Comment: Soooo... have you read my question and my answer post? The answer IS a part of the code I wrote. Also the edit that says "after I fixed it myself" is not exactly true... Jason and Philipp, thanks for your help - I'm feeling the IT room aura here already.

Comment: This answer uses only Jan's example, but with much more code. In my opinion, this answer does not add any value to the question asked. Anyway, maybe the code will help someone out there ;)

Comment: With all due respect to Jan, his answer's missing a bracket, therefore it's not a full answer. At least until he edits it :)